# Remove the shortcut of an application that was installed using Wine from the Unity Dash

Tags: unity, wine, unity-dash, shortcuts

How do I remove an application shortcut from the Unity Dash (not from the Unity Launcher)?

My specific issue is I tried to install a game using Wine a while ago. I then uninstalled the game, then uninstalled Wine. Today I found that shortcuts to the game (and other related content that came with it) remain when I push <kbd>Super</kbd> and type the game name. (Wine is not visible though.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably still have some hidden wine configuration files remaining.

```
rm -rf ~/.wine
rm -rf ~/.config/menus/applications-merged/wine*
rm -rf ~/.local/share/applications/wine
rm -rf ~/.local/share/desktop-directories/wine*
```